# Readding Checkbox property in a tableview in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I am new to JavaFx. I have designed a table thorugh scenebuilder where in column 1 I have a button and in column 2 I have a checkbox. What I want to get the checkbox property when I click the button. But the problem is I am always getting false as output. here is my code

Model.java

```
private boolean Active;     
    public boolean isActive() {
        return Active;
    }   
    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        Active = active;
    }
```

In my controller class I have designed the initialize() method below way

Controller.java

```
@FXML
private TableView<Model> tableBuilding;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Model,Boolean> colActive;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Model,Model> colAction; 
 @Override
        public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
//Containing the button         
colAction.setCellFactory(col -> {
                Button ShowButton = new Button("Show");

                TableCell<Model, Model> cell = new TableCell<Model, Model>() {
                    @Override
                    //Updating with the number of row 
                    public void updateItem(Model building, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(building, empty);
                        if (empty) {
                            setGraphic(null);
                        } else {
                            setGraphic(ShowButton);
                        }
                    }              
                };                                          
                ShowButton.setOnAction(event -> {

                TableRow row = cell.getTableRow();
                    Model building=(Model) row.getItem();


                    ObservableList<Model> data = tableBuilding.getItems();

                    for (Model item : data){
                        //check the boolean value of each item to determine checkbox state
                        System.out.println(item.isActive());
                    }

                });

                return cell ;
            });
//Containing the checkbox
colActive.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Model,Boolean>("Active"));
        colActive.setCellFactory(tc -> new CheckBoxTableCell<>());   

}
```

here `System.out.println(item.isActive());` is always retunrning false as output. How can I get the actual property of that checkbox? Can anyone help me please?

Comment: I am fairly new to JavaFX as well, but since you're already binding the `Active` property on `colActive`, your cell factory may only need to be `colActive.setCellFactory(tc -> new CheckBoxTableCell<>());` That would add the checkbox to the cell and automatically update the `Model` `Active` property as the checkbox is selected or unselected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can simplify your controller a bit. Try changing your controller code to:

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private TableView<Model> tableBuilding;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Model, Boolean> colActive;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Model, Model> colAction;

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {

        // Sample List
        ObservableList<Model> models = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        models.addAll(
                new Model(),
                new Model(),
                new Model()
        );

        tableBuilding.setItems(models);

        //Containing the button
        colAction.setCellFactory(col -> {
            Button ShowButton = new Button("Show");

            TableCell<Model, Model> cell = new TableCell<>() {
                @Override
                //Updating with the number of row
                public void updateItem(Model building, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(building, empty);
                    if (empty) {
                        setGraphic(null);
                    } else {
                        setGraphic(ShowButton);
                    }
                }
            };

            ShowButton.setOnAction(event -> {

                TableRow row = cell.getTableRow();
                Model building = (Model) row.getItem();

                System.out.println(building.getActive());

            });

            return cell;
        });

        //Containing the checkbox
        colActive.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("active"));
        colActive.setCellFactory(col -> new CheckBoxTableCell<>());

    }
}
```

Specifically, the last two lines of code; you shouldn't need to specify your own `TableCell` as the `CheckBoxTableCell` handles the updating of the `Model` on its own.

However, the `Model` class needs to be changed to update the `Active` field to a true property; otherwise, the `TableView` cannot update it properly.  The line in your controller `colActive.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Model,Boolean>("Active"));` tells the cell's value to be bound to a JavaFX Property in your `Model` class named `Active`, but there is no such property.

Here's the proper way to define the property:

```
public class Model {

    private SimpleBooleanProperty active = new SimpleBooleanProperty(true);

    public boolean getActive() {
        return active.get();
    }

    public SimpleBooleanProperty activeProperty() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active.set(active);
    }
}
```

Interestingly, this seems to be one of those cases where it's important to follow proper Java coding practices. The `Active` property should be lowercase here as well, not capitalized.

Comment: I have modified according to your instruction but still getting false as output when I am clicking `Show` button

Comment: Could you update your question to include the FXML code? We need to see a full working example to really help.  Also, your controller is not actually binding any data to the `TableView`. How is the table populated?

Comment: Full code is quite big 300-400 lines. I am populating my table through an observable list. All is working fine except  the checkbox value

Comment: I actually just noticed you do not have a valid property in your `Model` that can be bound to the `TableCell`. See my edit to this answer and try updating your `Model` class accordingly.

Comment: I have updated but now `item.getActive()` is always returning true

Comment: I've noticed other issues with your code and I'm working to build a sample on my own. :) I'll update the answer when I have it done!

Comment: I have updated my answer again. You'll need to make the `Active` property lowercase, which is the standard common practice in Java. Also, I simplified your `onAction` method for the button, as it will now only show the value for the currently selected row, instead of iterating through all of them.  Give that a try and let me know!

Comment: Actually, to be clear, it was the `activeProperty()` method that I had failed to change to `ActiveProperty()`. Either way, the new code above should work for you.

Comment: And Yes Finally I am getting correct Output. Thanks a lot

Comment: You are welcome. I apologize it took so much trial and error, but as I said, I'm fairly new as well. If you continue developing in JavaFX, though, I highly recommend studying Properties as they're quite essential!